# Parsing different JSON data in RecylerView OnItemclick from Previous Activity's RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, native

I have 2 Activity's. 1 activity with RecyclerView Imageview and text Containing men, women and kids with Below json

```
{ "Groups": [{"code":"1","Name":"MEN","url":""},{"code":"2","Name":"WOMEN","url":""},{"code":"3","Name":"CHIDREN","url:""}] }
```

2nd Activity with recyclerView displaying catagories of above groups I want to parse diiferent json data In same activity (*for eg if user clicks on MEN so catagories of men will be parsed in ReclerView if user clicks on women then women's catagories*)  as shown in image [1st Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJbYX.jpg)

[2nd activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np1Ev.jpg)

How will I parse different json data in 2nd activity on condition of what item is clicked in RecyclerView fromw 1st activity

Comment: Pass the id/code from 1st activity by intent(bundle). And using the id you can find the Category.

Comment: you can do it with `intent.putExtra`

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can put an entire JSONObject as a string. like this:

```
i.putString("Men", jsonObj.toString);
```

And then in the Activity2 you could

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("Men"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add one more field like

> {"code":"20","Name":"MEN ACCESSORIES","url":"","category":"MEN"}

and than compare to that two field and get the sorted data. you can also use a comman id for compare.